# How do I launch Starbound and the dedicated server from Steam

Tags: steam, starbound

I'm using the dedicated server to play with my friends, but if I have already launched the game from Steam, when I select Starbound again and this time, I instead select "dedicated server", nothing happens. The dedicated server does not launch or anything.

Note: I'm doing this by right clicking the Steam icon in the taskbar, selecting Starbound from the recent games at the top. This gives me four options, including the aforementioned game and server.

I know I can go to the Starbound folder to launch the server that way, but it would be easier and tidier to be able to launch it from the Starbound launcher in Steam.

Comment: You could create a runnable file on windows to launch the steam game and then launch the server or something like that, put the file on your desktop and run it whenever you want to play with friends.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only solution is to **launch Starbound, then launch the server using the starbound folder.** If you launch the server first, Steam will interpret that as Starbound running, and will not let you launch the actual game. If you launch the game first, Steam will think that you have launched Starbound, hence you will be unable to launch the server directly.

Answer (score 1):

Add the server executable via the add a non-steam game to your library menu
Then you can launch it along starbound wether it is before or after you launch the game

If you want to launch both the server and the game from the entry in your library, you can't, you cannot launch the same program twice with steam

As a side note:

A dedicated server is designed to run 24/7, so people can play on it even if you are not playing.

If you want to have your friends join you only when you are playing, then you can invite them via the invite to game option when you right click a friend in the friends list

If you want to have your server running 24/7, execute the starbound_server.exe, and let it run

http://starbounder.org/Guide:Setting_Up_Multiplayer

You can always [setup a windows task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx) so the server is launched whenever your computer reboots or when the server crashes
Or for setting a timeframe on which the server is active

Comment: None of this actually answers the question

Comment: Updated the answer